# Insert 10000 records from C# into SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a C# console program

- Selects 10000 records from `Input` table (`Keyid varchar(4), Address varchar(100), Name varchar(100)`).
- for each record from `Input` table, it calls an API that returns data (if person works in that address, status is OK else NOT OK, also returns address type-place of interest or residential, commercial etc.) that needs to be saved in one main table and a detail table.

`Main` table:

```
1001|JOE STILTON| 2 MAIN ST, SALEM,PA| OK|4/15/2014
```

`Detail` table:

```
1001|PHARMACY
1001|COMMERCIAL
```

i.e Joe works in a pharmacy which is also a commercial bldg.

Right now, I call the API. then I call a method,

```
private static void insertTable(string keyid, DateTime updDate, string name, string address,string status)
{
     Int32 rowsAffected = 0;
     string connectionString = GetConnectionString();

     SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
     connection.Open();

     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("google.usp_InsertCompanyAddrComponents", connection);
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     cmd.CommandTimeout = 90;
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@keyid", SqlDbType.VarChar);
     cmd.Parameters["@keyid"].Value = keyid;        
     cmd.Parameters.Add( new SqlParameter("@dateverified", updDate));
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
     cmd.Parameters["@name"].Value = name;
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@address", SqlDbType.VarChar);
     cmd.Parameters["@address"].Value = address;
     cmd.Parameters.Add( new SqlParameter("@status", status));

     try
     {
         rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
     catch (Exception ep)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(ep.Message);
     }

     connection.Close();
}
```

Then, I call another similar method that inserts into detail table.

Since I have to do this for 10,000 records at a time, there is lot of I/O. how can I change to do batch insert? all 10000 insert at a time?

Thanks
R

Comment: Like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp) ?

Comment: Have you considered [`SqlBulkCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx)

Comment: @MarcGravell, Iam not sure how to convert my above program to SQLBulkcopy. Should i store each API call result to a list and then sqlbulkcopy??

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look into table types in SQL Server. You can pass two table types in stored procedure and do required operations directly over there.

Here is my sample stored proc

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_AssociateTags]  
@Tags AS UDT_Tag READONLY  
AS  
SET XACT_ABORT ON  
BEGIN TRAN  
   --Insert into Tag Master  
   INSERT INTO dbo.TagMaster  
     (   
     Name  
     ,IsActive  
     )  
   VALUES  ( '', -- Name - varchar(50)  
       1  -- IsActive - bit  
     )  

   DECLARE @TagId AS INT  
   SET @TagId=SCOPE_IDENTITY()  

   INSERT INTO dbo.TagCollection  
           ( TagNumber, TagId )  
   SELECT TagNumber, @TagId  FROM @Tags t  
   WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.TagCollection WHERE TagNumber = t.TagNumber)  
COMMIT TRAN  
SET XACT_ABORT OFF
```

**Script to test this stored procedure**

```
--DECLARE @hello as UDT_Tag  
--INSERT INTO @hello VALUES('vaibhav')  
--INSERT INTO @hello VALUES('Shantanu')  
--INSERT INTO @hello VALUES('Sam')  
--INSERT INTO @hello VALUES('Aakash')  
--EXEC usp_AssociateTags @hello  

--SELECT * FROM dbo.TagCollection
```

**C# code to consume this procedure**

```
SqlParameter Tags = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@Tags"
                  , Value = entity.Tags.ToDataTable() 
                  , Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
                  , SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured, TypeName="UDT_Tag" };

SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(tran, CommandType.StoredProcedure
               , "usp_AssociateTags", Tags);
```

### [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39161/C-and-Table-Value-Parameters)